# What is this plant (maybe melon/squash related)?

Tags: identification

You can see the seed in the lower right. Could be related to a melon/squash/zucchini but unsure. May be too early as it is just starting to show it's true leaves.

[image]

Comment: I'm growing squash, pumpkin, and aubergine. Those leaves look different.

Answer (score 1):

If the leaves are smaller than they appear in the picture, it could be a cucumber. That seed coat looks a lot like a giant cucumber seed (unless you have a great camera, in which case it might be normal-sized).

I'm fairly confident that it's not a muskmelon, due to how jagged the leaf edges are. However, muskmelon, cucumber, and kiwano seeds all look about the same. It could be kiwano. Muskmelon seeds are thicker than cucumber seeds, though (and sometimes they're orange).

It's not a watermelon.

If the seed picture isn't very representative, I might guess a squash. You can tell a squash by how the leaves smell.

Comment: What distinctive smell do squash leaves have?

Comment: @moinudin You just have to know it, but cucumber and melon leaves don't have much of a smell at all, while squash leaves have a strong smell. The next time you see a squash, smell it's leaves, and you'll probably remember the smell thereafter (you may have to touch the leaves before the smell is released, but it should release fairly easily).